# What type of speech is "In person"?

Tags: questions, spoken-english

What type of speech would the phrase: "In person" be part of the English Language?

Comment: It's a preposition-based ***adverbial*** element, so *He came **in person*** is syntactically much the same as *He came **at once*** - or non-prepositional *He came **willingly***.

Answer (score 1):

It is a prepositional phrase  "In" is a preposition "person" is a noun.

Prepositional phrases have many uses in a sentence.  A common use of "in person" would be as an adjunct of manner, giving some more information on how an action occurred.

> He came to see me in person.

It also becomes lexicalised (made into a single word) as "in-person".  This word might be an adjective:

> We had an in-person meeting.

Comment: Is there a prepositional phrase for when you are in a video call with someone? in person means in one's physical presence. What would the one for in video contact through an electronic video call be?

Comment: You'd probably just use the name of the technology that you were using.  "I'm going to meet on zoom" or "on facetime" or "on skype" etc.  Or even just "I'm going to skype him"

Comment: Is there something like saying: "In call"? What were wanted to talk about the time you were on a video call with someone. Face-to-face. How would you describe being in contact with someone but not face-to-face?

Comment: Well, like I said, you'd refer to the technology you used.  "I met him on Skype".   So not "in call" but "on Skype" or "on the phone"